# LMSSetValue for API wrapper not setting value gotten from LMSGetValue, they differ?

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

I have the get and set code in new.js:

```
APIClass.prototype.LMSGetValue = function (element) {
   var value = GetValueJson(element, '1.2', 'LMSGetValue');  
   return value;
}

APIClass.prototype.LMSSetValue = function (element, value) {
  SetValueJson(element, value, '1.2', 'LMSSetValue');
  return "true";
}

API_1484_11_Class.prototype.GetValue = function (element) {
var value = GetValueJson(element, '2004 3rd Edition', 'GetValue');
  return value;
}

API_1484_11_Class.prototype.SetValue = function (element, value) {
   SetValueJson(element, value, '2004 3rd Edition', 'SetValue');
return "true";
}

function SetValueJson(key1, value1, scormVersion, methodCalled) {
  if (key1 = "cmi.suspend_data") {
    value1 = "none";
  }
    var obj = {
    key: key1,
    value: value1
  }
  setValuesArray.push(obj);

  for (var i = setValuesArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var array = setValuesArray[i];
  if (array.key === key1) {
    alert("returning value for key= " + setValuesArray[i].key + " with value as: " +  setValuesArray[i].value);
    return setValuesArray[i].value;
   }
  }
  //return value1;
}
```

function GetValueJson(key, scormVersion, methodCalled) {

```
if (scormVersion == '1.2' && methodCalled == 'LMSGetValue')
{
 alert("key that must be set for 1.2: " + key);
}

if (scormVersion == '2004 3rd Edition' && methodCalled == 'GetValue') {
  alert("key that must be set 2004: " + key);
}

if (key = "cmi.completion_status") {
  value = "not completed"; 
}

if (key = "cmi.location") {
  value = "";
}

if (key = "cmi.suspend_data") {
  value = "";
}

 return value;
}
```

What happens is when I want to set a value(SetValueJson) and it differs from the value I got in GetValueJson I get a popup stating that the persistent data could not be stored. How can I get round this problem? Some modules use 1.2 and others 2004

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Observations about the sample code you provided:

`if (key1 = "cmi.suspend_data")` and `if (key = "cmi.completion_status")` look like typos to me. Are you trying to assign a value here? It's generally considered a bad practice to assign values in a conditional statement, I'm inclined to think these are typos.

[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)ing your code also points out `setValuesArray` is undefined, and `value` is undefined in your `GetValueJson` function.

Another consideration: SCORM's `cmi.suspend_data` has very limited space, it's very common to accidentally try and store more than the allowed amount. SCORM 1.2 provides 4096 bytes, whereas SCORM 2004 provides 64,000. If you're using SCORM 1.2 in your testing, I'd check to ensure your string isn't more than 4096 bytes.

**Update:**

Upon re-reading your code, I see that your post is tagged `SCORM2004` yet you're specifying SCORM 1.2 elements:

```
SetValueJson(element, value, '1.2', 'LMSSetValue');

function SetValueJson(key1, value1, scormVersion, methodCalled)
```

Your code specifies SCORM 1.2 in `SetValueJson` and `GetValueJson`, and uses SCORM 1.2 methods `LMSSetValue` and `LMSGetValue`, yet it also contains SCORM 2004 CMI elements `cmi.location` and `cmi.completion_status`.  SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004 syntax can't be mixed, so you'll need to correct your code to use one or the other exclusively.

Comment: yes thanks I realized it and fixed it, but still not sure how it wants to set a value that differs from the one I just got?